# Error in Android studio 2,2

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.5.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.5/gradle-4.5.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.5/gradle-4.5.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.5/gradle-4.5.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.5/gradle-4.5.jar
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.5/gradle-4.5.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.5/gradle-4.5.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse **gradle** with **android plugin for gradle**.

You are looking for a **plugin v.4.5** and it **doesn't exist**.

```
dependencies {
     //Change this line !!
     //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.5'
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

If you want to use **gradle 4.5** you have to change the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file with:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5-all.zip
```

Comment: still dont get it